EAGLECAD Create a device with one mulit-instance package
I need to create some switches as devices. The switches consists, from the PCB-side of view, only of a bunch of ST2,8 connectors. These are based on the connectors within the existing con-rib.lib.
To understand the schematic more easily, I created symbols for every switch variant (ON-OFF, ON-ON, ON-OFF-ON). Symbols are already created, package is imported, but now I need to connect every pin to an instance of the same package. How can I create copies of that package within the library/devide definition?
Currently, when I try to connect the symbol-pins to that package I get the obvious hint that the package doesn't have enough pads for the symbol.
For the ON-ON and ON-OFF variant I would need two ST2,8 packages, for the ON-OFF-ON variant even three.
My goal is to add the device (KCD1-101) into my schematic and then be able to place the ST2,8 separatly anywhere on pcb. If this is not possible, than it's OK when both ST2,8 are placed at the same time.
Any hint is highle appreciated.
As I create this by a script, when requested, I can share it.

Is not possible, because of the reasons explained below.
However, I could find a workaround for what I want to achieve, at least partly. The picture shows what I want to do. I now may add some variants of the "package" with different layout configurations.


This is not possible in Eagle.
A device can have exactly one package (or zero for a symbol only device).
If you want multiple packages, you will need to split your symbol into multiple smaller symbols and make several devices one for each.

To understand why, consider that if you can place different bits of the package wherever you like, then you would need to have multiple origins and centroid information, which requires each part to be its own instance.

Basically I understand what you mean. But this is also true for symbols. There are symbols where I can have mutliple instance in one package (e.g. Quad-OP-Amps). Same procedure maybe for packages. Why not having multiple "packages" for one symbol? This would be handy for devices like the dual switches (KCD1-20x) where each side of the swiitch is placed on a different PCB, without loosing the "this is a switch"-information.
However I can solve my problem by defining an own package, aggregated by several ST2,8. One variant where the ST2,8 are horizontally stacked, the other vertically...

@Benny A schematic is topological, so it is perfectly reasonable to have multiple symbols for  these same part dotted around. A PCB is mechanically fixed, a component has a defined shape and size. If bits of the component can be placed arbitrarily, then it is not a single PCB mounted part, e.g. it must be mounted on cables or by some other flexible means. At which point your schematic should be describing the mounting points, e.g. as connectors or solder pads, with separate annotations of what those connectors attach to.

If you're doing something like a flex PCB then it becomes a bit weird because the shape of the board is no longer mechanically fixed. But even then you are still having multiple mounting points so as far as the PCB is concerned you again still have multiple mounting pads for some external component, so the schematic would again contain the connectors, with annotations of what they attach to.

yes you are right. My switches are connected to wires, which are connected to the contactor on the PCB. My only goal by this approach is to see the "function" of the switch, whether it is a ON-OFF, ON-ON or ON-OFF-ON, directly on the PCB. I find this handy because I don't need to struggle finding a description for a contactor. I can now just look at the schematic and instantly see how things has to be wired up. Easier to understand, easier to test against. Example will follow when done.
@all Thank you for your thoughts on this - highly  appreciated
